# Unable to access flask server hosted on azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, remote-server

I have a flask server hosted on my azure vm.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host="127.0.0.1", port=4400)
```

On vm, I can access the server via the address 127.0.0.1:4400
Now I want to be able to access this server from outside the vm i.e. my local computer.

I have already added the inbound security rule as below:

[image]

I have also added the same inbound rule on the VM's firewall on port 4400

Still I am unable to access the flask server via publicIP:4400 (publicIP is the public IP of my VM as displayed on the azure portal)

What could be the issue?

Comment: you might have nsg attached at subnet level\nic level, check that, also, change host to `*` in your app run

Comment: @4c74356b41 app crashes on changing host to * with the following error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

There are no subnet levels, checked that

Comment: ah, it might be `0.0.0.0` dont remember, try that

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: @4c74356b41 for some reason, using 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1, I cant access the server locally on the vm either.

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your issue, there are two possible reasons.

1. You must listen to the IP 0.0.0.0 so that it's possible to access from the Internet. The 127.0.0.1 is just a loopback IP for the test in the localhost. So 4c74356b41 is right in this way.
2. If you also cannot access the app from the Internet when you change the IP into 0.0.0.0. Then it must be the rules issue. You should check your VM networking if it's the same NSG for your subnet and NIC. If not, add the rule to allow the port 4400 in both NSGs. Then you also should check if the public IP is associated directly with your VM, or it's associated with the load balancer and your VM is just in the backend of the load balancer. If it's a load balancer, you still need to add the load balancer rule to allow the port 4400.

Take a check for the two possible reasons.

Comment: Thank you. However after hosting the flask app on 0.0.0.0 I was unable to access it internally, but it was connecting externally. I dont know if that is normal behaviour or not though.

Comment: @hsnsd It's also accessible locally, you can access it use the URL localhost:4400.